# What is the episode of scrubs where they end with Boston - More Than A Feeling?

Tags: identify-this-episode, scrubs

I'm searching for the episode of scrubs where they get an air band together and at the end they play air instruments to "More Than A Feeling" by Boston.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

["My Half-Acre"](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0763007/combined) (Season 5, Episode 9) .

> .D. meets the klutzy Julie, and when he becomes smitten, Elliot attempts to help out with romance advice; Carla tries to find Cox's soft side when he refuses to kiss his son; **Turk and Janitor put together an air band to win a contest**, but Kelso gives them a tremendous obstacle.

Here it is:

Comment: Aaah man that brings such a smile to my face (-;